# Video Quality Assessment (No-Reference)

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-quality

I am looking to analyze the quality of videos using some no-reference methods. ie. I don't have a reference video to compare my videos with.

I want to identify frame-freezes, jitter, jerkiness etc. Basically, temporal artifacts.

There's a lot of academic literature available for this (eg. [here](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1186/1687-5281-2014-40)), but I'm trying to figure out if there is an open source library / tool that I could use. Would this be possible using tools like FFMPEG?

Comment: ffmpeg mainly is for reading/writing video. I want similar tools too.

Comment: What is the video production context for this?  While video quality matters in video production, I can't think of a situation where you would need to measure the quality objectively though.  Either it is good enough for your purposes subjectively or it isn't.

Comment: @AJHenderson, it's a live-streaming use-case where we want to analyze the quality of video that the viewers saw.  While we can do a subjective assessment of the videos, it's not scalable.

Comment: @GufranPathan for what purpose though?  This sounds more like it is a software development question for a video viewing system than something related to Video Production.  I don't want to close this if there is a good use case that fits within scope, but I'm struggling to see one.

Comment: @AJHenderson Quality of Experience testing is a growing part of distribution monitoring. It is definitely in-scope for a broadcast engineer. (In other words, it is something I've worked on in my day job.) I'm not positive that is on topic the way the site's scope is written, but it is a pretty good yard stick in my book.

Comment: @MichaelLiebman yeah, that's why I haven't closed it yet.  It's certainly borderline.  I guess part of my concern is it seems like the border is probably at the point between using an existing tool to make sure something is going ok vs trying to build your own tool.  I'm not sure which of those this is trying to accomplish.  Making sure a delivery is successful seems like it is probably on topic.  Building your own custom distribution platform from source probably is not.  Using existing distribution systems probably is.

Answer (score 2):

Freely available video quality of experience tools are quite rare and probably aren't going to work for your use case out of the box. The [Netflix VMAF algorithm](https://github.com/Netflix/vmaf) recently became available as an FFmpeg filter. The [MSU VQMT](http://www.compression.ru/video/quality_measure/video_measurement_tool.html) is one of the more mature tools, but is only free for non-commercial use.

There are several (and some even good) commercial QoE monitoring systems available, if you have the budget.

Comment: VMAF is good, but apparently it is still a reference-based approach. Right?